# spring-boot-chaos-monkey - Changing the assualts/watcher configuration on multiple instances of same application

Tags: spring-boot-chaos-monkey

Spring-boot-chaos-monkey works really well with an application running on my local machine or if there is not more then one instance of the application.
Now, imagine that my application has 2 instances and hosted on aws behind load balancer and I wanted to change the assualts or watcher configuration. How, can I do that?

Because if I will change the configuration by hitting the rest endpoint then the call will redirect to one of the instance and other instances state will be old.
I can think of a solution where I can store this inside data base and both the application instances can sync from database and update the config. but is there a better way or default provisioning for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Since release [2.5.0 Chaos Monkey](https://github.com/codecentric/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.5.0) supports the feature Toggle Library [Unleashed](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash).

So if you can get yourself a unleash instance you most likekly can control it through that.

See the appropriate doc link for [how to use the feature flags](https://codecentric.github.io/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/latest/#_using_unleash_to_control_toggles)